# How to remove a channel from a midi dataset

Tags: python, midi

I am working with midi dataset and I want to remove some channels from it during the pre-processing stage. Please how do i get this done?

Im working with a large dataset, so it will be difficult to do it manually

i expect the some channel to be removed

Comment: can you show the source you use to load the midi data?

Comment: thanks @Lee , I am using the code from JAMBOT it can be found here   [link](https://github.com/brunnergino/JamBot.git) _italic_ **bold** `code` the code inside the notebook data_class.py shows how the midi dataset is loaded.